# How to pass list string to JLabel and show in JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I have been working on this program and I am having a hard time getting the result to show on the window that pops up. I have the correct output showing in the console when the program is ran but I need it to show up in the window under the radio buttons when the radio button is selected. Thanks in advance, any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
import TrySource.TryWindow;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;


public class TrySomethingNew extends JFrame
{

  // Radio buttons for selecting colors
  private JRadioButton jrbMexican, jrbItalian;
        JLabel jlblResult; 

  // Declare a panel for displaying message
  private TryWindow TryWindow;

  // Main method
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    TrySomethingNew frame = new TrySomethingNew();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setTitle("Try Something New");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

  public TrySomethingNew() 
  {
    // Create a MovingMessageCanvas instance and set colors
    TryWindow = new TryWindow("Let's try this.");
    TryWindow.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    // Panel to hold radio buttons
    JPanel jpRadioButtons = new JPanel();
    jpRadioButtons.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.TitledBorder("Select A Food Genre"));
    jpRadioButtons.add(jrbMexican = new JRadioButton("Mexican"));
    jpRadioButtons.add(jrbItalian = new JRadioButton("Italian"));


    // Group radio buttons
    ButtonGroup btg = new ButtonGroup();
    btg.add(jrbMexican);
    btg.add(jrbItalian);
    
    //Panel to hold result
    JPanel jpResultPanel = new JPanel();
    jpResultPanel.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.TitledBorder("Result"));    

    // Place panels in the frame
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(TryWindow, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(jpRadioButtons, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(jpResultPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    

    // Register listeners with the buttons

    jrbMexican.addItemListener(new EventListener());
    jrbItalian.addItemListener(new EventListener());
    
    
  }//end main

  // Handle radio button selections
  class EventListener implements ItemListener 
  {
      
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) 
    {
      if (jrbMexican.isSelected())
      {
        java.util.List<String> mexicanList = Arrays.asList("Jose Locos\n853 N Glenstone Ave, Springfield, MO 65802\n(417) 831-1300",
        "Amigos Mexican Restaurant\n2118 S Campbell Ave, Springfield, MO 65807\n(417) 887-1401");
        
        Random randomizer = new Random();
        String random = mexicanList.get(randomizer.nextInt(mexicanList.size()));
        System.out.println(random);
        
        
      }//end if jrbMexican isSelected
      
      if (jrbItalian.isSelected())
      {
        java.util.List<String> italianList = Arrays.asList("Zios Italian Kitchen\n1249 E Kingsley St, Springfield, MO 65804\n(417) 889-1919",
        "Bambinos Cafe\n1141 E Delmar St, Springfield, MO 65807\n(417) 862-9999");
        
        Random randomizer = new Random();
        String random = italianList.get(randomizer.nextInt(italianList.size()));
        System.out.println(random);
        
      }//end if jrbItalian isSelected
    }//end itemStateChanged
  }//end eventListener
}//end TrySomethingNew
```

```js
package TrySource;

// TryWindow.java: Display a message on a JPanel
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TryWindow extends JPanel 
{
  /** The message to be displayed */
  private String message = "Try Something New";

  /** The x coordinate where the message is displayed */
  private int xCoordinate = 465;

  /** The y coordinate where the message is displayed */
  private int yCoordinate = 40;

  /** Indicate whether the message is displayed in the center */
  private boolean centered;

  /** The interval for moving the message horizontally and vertically */
  private int interval = 10;

  /** Default constructor */
  public TryWindow() 
  {
      
  }

  /** Constructor with a message parameter */
  public TryWindow(String message) 
  {
    this.message = message;
  }

  /** Return message */
  public String getMessage() 
  {
    return message;
  }

  /** Set a new message */
  public void setMessage(String message) 
  {
    this.message = message;
    repaint();
  }

  /** Return xCoordinator */
  public int getXCoordinate() 
  {
    return xCoordinate;
  }

  /** Set a new xCoordinator */
  public void setXCoordinate(int x) 
  {
    this.xCoordinate = x;
    repaint();
  }

  /** Return yCoordinator */
  public int getYCoordinate() 
  {
    return yCoordinate;
  }

  /** Set a new yCoordinator */
  public void setYCoordinate(int y) 
  {
    this.yCoordinate = y;
    repaint();
  }

  /** Return centered */
  public boolean isCentered() 
  {
    return centered;
  }

  /** Set a new centered */
  public void setCentered(boolean centered) 
  {
    this.centered = centered;
    repaint();
  }

  /** Return interval */
  public int getInterval() 
  {
    return interval;
  }

  /** Set a new interval */
  public void setInterval(int interval) 
  {
    this.interval = interval;
    repaint();
  }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
  {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if (centered) 
    {
      // Get font metrics for the current font
      FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();

      // Find the center location to display
      int stringWidth = fm.stringWidth(message);
      int stringAscent = fm.getAscent();
      // Get the position of the leftmost character in the baseline
      xCoordinate = getWidth() / 2 - stringWidth / 2;
      yCoordinate = getHeight() / 2 + stringAscent / 2;
    }

    g.drawString(message, xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
  }

  }
```

Comment: `add(TryWindow, BorderLayout.CENTER);` should be removed and jlblResult should get a sufficiently large preferred and minimal size and added to the result panel with a BorderLayout too at the center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private TextArea textArea1;
```

//declear the variable

```
 textArea1 = new TextArea();
```

// put it in the constructor

```
jpResultPanel.add(textArea1);
textArea1.setVisible(true);
```

put these lines after
// Register listeners with the buttons
AND

```
textArea1.setText(random);
```

put it where you are printing the result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the Textarea like TextArea textArea1 = new TextArea();
and add it to the frame and than show your result in this area by calling its setText method in this way you can show your required info in this area under the result